# How come WPF ComboBox ItemsSource Binding doesn't update when set?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, dependencies

I have the following inside a user control called `UserInputOutput`:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Background="White" Visibility="{Binding InputEnumVisibility}"     
          FontSize="{Binding FontSizeValue}" Width="Auto" Padding="10,0,5,0"     
          ItemsSource="{Binding EnumItems}"     
          SelectedIndex="{Binding EnumSelectedIndex}"/>
```

I have several bindings here which all work great except ItemsSource.  Here is my Dependency Property and public variable.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<String> EnumItems
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<String>)GetValue(EnumItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(EnumItemsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty EnumItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("EnumItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>),typeof(UserInputOutput)
```

All the Bindings are set in XAML except the ComboBox's ItemSource.  This has to be set at runtime.  In my code I use the following:

```cs
ObservableCollection<string> enumItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
UserInputOutput.getEnumItems(enumItems, enumSelectedIndex, ui.ID, ui.SubmodeID);
instanceOfUserInputOutput.EnumItems = enumItems;
```

I run this code after the XAML is loaded from a file.  The `instaceOfUserInputOutput.EnumItems` contains the correct items after I set it equal to enumItems, but it doesn't show up in the combo box in my program.

Not sure where I'm going wrong here. Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your ViewModel class (the one that is used as a source of binding) implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Otherwise update won't work.

Then, in your setter method, do this:

```
set
{
     // set whatever internal properties you like
     ...

     // signal to bound view object which properties need to be refreshed
     OnPropertyChanged("EnumItems");
}
```

where OnProperyChanged method is like this:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

BTW, I don't know why you need to declare EnumItems as a dependency property. Having it as a class field would work fine, unless you want to use it as a target for binding (right now it is used as a binding source).

Comment: I have had to use dependency properties because the elements in my UserControl can't have the Name field.  If I can't use the Name field then I can't access the ItemsSource without some other method being used.  The other Dependency properties you see in the code work perfect.

Comment: Also, I currently don't implement the interface you mentioned.  I just inherit off UserControl.

Comment: @B-Rad, If you want to populate some control through binding you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface, otherwise update won't work. Other bindings probably set at the time control is instantiated, and don't change while object is alive.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm guessing I will probably have to create another class that implements that interface.

Comment: If you follow MVVM pattern, then your ViewModel object usually implements INotifyProperyChanged. This is the best approach in my opinion, and from your code snippet you almost follow it. Create a ViewModel class that exposes bindings and implements INotifyPropertyChanged, then assing your ViewModel as a binding source for your control.